# Error jsp tomcat 8

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat8, digital-ocean

I have installed a Web module, developed in java, on my local machine, and it worked.

But I tried to make it work in the droplets and I could not, I created 3 different oceans servers digitally, with different versions of Tomcat S.O and nothing has worked.

The java application working on my local machine:

[image: 1]

The error produced when testing it on a digital-ocean server:

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share the code. Probably you should import the  TCJBeanPropiedades class in your JSP file.